# Computer loses power when bumped

Tags: power-supply

Recently I noticed that my computer suddenly shuts down. First I thought it overheats. But after digging a bit deeper I found the reason.

When someone nudges the computer it switches off (like you hit the power switch). It doesn't need to be a hard knock/bump. So it seems like a hardware failure, but I have no idea where to look further.

Has anyone of you noticed such behaviour? What can be the cause?

Comment: Maybe the cables from the power supply are loose. You will have to open it to see if the connections are okay.

Also my friend has a HP laptop and this is also happens to him, it seems that is a battery problem so if your computer is a HP laptop you should look into it.

Comment: Indeed. Like the PC I had at school. The SATA cable was so loose, one kicked the table = no PC. :)

Comment: Laptop or Desktop?

Comment: It is a desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a loose connection somewhere or a broken wire.  I would just try nudging every wire you can, narrowing down the problem.

Comment: I tried kickin the computer itself as well as some cables, but nothing happened. I guess I'll have to wait for my kids to kick the computer. They had more luck. :-) So as I can't reproduce it at the moment I'll close it.